# Lightswitch html one property (Boolean) changed another property isVisible changes accordingly

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I have a MachineProcess Entity which has a Boolean Property IsGroup, In AddandEditMachineProcess Screen, I want tab PartGroup Change Visibility according value IsGroup. my code like below it's not work.

```
 myapp.AddEditMachineProcess.Details_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
// Write code here.  
contentItem.details.addChangeListener("IsGroup", function (e) {
    var isGroup = contentItem.value.MachineProcess.isGroup;
    var partGroup  = contentItem.findItem("PartGroups");
    if(isGroup){partGroup.isVisible}});};
```

please help for correct code , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar based on a Boolean value being true or false. if this Boolean value is saved within a table in a database then something like this will work:

```
if (screen.MachineProcess.IsGroup == true) {
    screen.findContentItem("PartGroups").isVisible = true;
}
else
{
    screen.findContentItem("PartGroups").isVisible = false;
}
```